# Form inside forEach/ui:repeat not working

Tags: jsf, jstl

I am having some trouble with forms inside both forEach and ui:repeat. The action associated with the commandButton does not seem to be invoked at all, the page just refreshes. h:messages is not displaying any messages either.

**The code**

```
<c:forEach items="#{newsController.newsList}" var="news" >
     <h:form>
         <h:inputText value="#{newsController.comment.text}" />
         <h:commandButton value="Post comment" action="#{newsController.postComment(news.id)}" />
     </h:form>
</c:forEach>
```

The form is working as expected if i place it outside the forEach or ui:repeat tag.

The postComment method

```
public String postComment(int newsId){
    News news = newsEJB.getById(newsId);

    comment.setCreatedAt(new Date());
    comment.setNews(news);
    commentEJB.persist(comment);

    return "news-detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

Comment: What about placing `<h:form>` tags outside of the loop tags ?

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: How does `postComment(Integer ..)` look like ?

Comment: Edited the question. I have placed breakpoints in this method to detect if it is being invoked or not.